Free software for making presentations in Youtube for Windows
I want to make some videos in Youtube which would have small animated features, like words which appears like being typed when being shown, or growing bars for statistics, things that I see in many videos, but that I have no idea which softwares they are made of. I could do things with non specific softwares but they would take much more time and I'm pretty sure people are using softwares which are much more specific and which I'm not aware of.
Here there is an example: example video
Are there free software to do animations like this?

I created something little different, but you can create presentation like this (video from Wikipedia article about cats)

@xralf thanks, I should have mentioned I wanted it for Windows

I'm not sure why you think e.g. that video uses anything specific. All I see is basic video editing, with some animated hand appearing and following a pattern for each digit. Random preset could be reused for that since all the digits look more or less the same, e.g. all the 1s have a messy shape.

@Destroy666 because adding an animated hand for each character would take a lot of time to do . Also adding an animated number for each digit

you can use libre office presentations and do a screen recording. the snipping tool is part of windows and can do screen recordings
